# When I run 'gem list' from within any of my projects I get the following output

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
user@user:~/Workspace/fq$ gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.21)
```

Why isn't it showing all the gems I have installed?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using `rvm`? If so, those gems might be installed under different gemsets.

- Run `rvm gemset list` to display all gemsets.
- Run `rvm gemset use #{gemset_name}` to use this `gemset_name`,
  then run `gem list` again.

Comment: I ran `rvm gemset list` and got the following out put `gemset for ruby-1.9.2-290 (found n path_to/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290)` `=> global`      So I guess I only have the global gemset?